# Erro sobre orientação em criação de módulos no livro Head First Python usando o Windows

Tags: python-3.x, módulo-python

Olá! Estou lendo o livro Head First Python e surgiu uma dúvida quanto a criação de módulo e distribuição do mesmo usando o Windows. Seguindo as orientações do autor, criei um arquivo.py com uma função def específica e salvei numa pasta do Desktop com nome Módulo. A seguir, criei um arquivo setup.py seguindo as orientações do autor e salvei na mesma pasta Módulo. Assim, são 2 arquivos dentro da pasta Módulo (arquivo.py, com a função def e setup.py). Adiante, o autor diz que é preciso construir uma distribuição seguindo os passos: Abrir uma janela de terminal 'dentro' da pasta Módulo (Como assim?? Abrir terminal dentro da pasta??), depois digitar o comando: python3 setup.py sdist, mas acredito que ele usava o Linux e disse que pra Windows seria "só" substituir python3 por: c:\Python3|\python.exe, o que NÃO FUNCIONOU!! Ou seja, foram 2 furos nesse livro: o 1º ao dizer que abro o terminal dentro da pasta Módulo e o 2º com essa sequência maluca de comandos. Enfim, depois criei um novo programa no IDLE usando import Módulo, salvei numa pasta deu ERRO na execução dizendo não ter achado a função def que eu havia especificado no Módulo. Decidi então, criar o módulo.py na mesma pasta do programinha que eu havia escrito pra chamar o módulo com a função def, e NÃO FUNCIONOU. Alguém pode me dizer o que está acontecendo?. Obrigada.

seguem os códigos, ambos estão na MESMA pasta:

LISTA.py
import nester

CAST = ['joão','maria','jose']

imprime(CAST)

nester.py

def imprime(lista):

```
for i in lista:
    if isinstance(i,list):
                    
        imprime(i)
    else:

        print(i)
```

Answer (score 0):

Creio que quando ele esta querendo dizer que é para abrir o terminal dentro da pasta, é acessar pasta através do CMD do windows ( prompt de comando ), para isto faça o seguinte:

- Abra o menu iniciar > Digite "cmd" sem as aspas > Irá abrir até o prompt de comando ( uma tela preta );
- Navegue até a pasta que deseja ( segundo você, esta no Desktop ) então digite:

`cd C:/Desktop/nome-da-pasta`

Troque o nome da pasta pelo nome da pasta que você criou no seu Desktop

Agora a sua segunda pergunta, para você criar um módulo e importar ele em outra parte do código, basta você criar um módulo, por exemplo "lista.py" e dentro dela tem a função:

```
def imprimir(lista)
for i in lista:
    if isinstance(i,list):             
        imprime(i)
    else:
        print(i)
```

Então, na outra parte do seu código que você irá usar esta lista, você precisa importar esta parte importando da seguinte maneira

`from .lista import imprimir`
Veja que lista se refere ao arquivo (lista.py) e o imprimir se refere a função que você esta chamando dentro do arquivo .lista, para importar outra função, basta adicionar a vírgula e em seguida chamar a função seguinte.

E sempre que for usar, digite

`imprimir(valores)`

e assim para as demais funções.